# Two way BTC payments for Ethereum smart contract

Tags: dapps, bitcoin

Are there any good ways to make two way payments by BTC to Ethereum smart contract?

Simply put, I want to make a button "Pay by BTC" for DAPP, but it could make a return payment to the return address. Are there really working tools/services for this?

This is fine if the «bridge» will take small fee or use not the best exchange rate. I understand it.

Comment: **BTC Relay**: "Unfortunately not. BTCRelays makes it possible to, on the ethereum side, verify that a given transaction has been executed on the bitcoin blockchain."

Comment: **ShapeShift**: "Prior to February our system did not detect ETH deposits made from smart contracts. Now users can deposit to our ETH deposit address from an ETH smart contract. Howeber, we do not create specifically ETH contract addresses for deposit."

Answer (score 2):

explore the solution http://btcrelay.org/

it is presented as A bridge between the Bitcoin blockchain & Ethereum smart contracts

> BTC Relay is a building block that allows Ethereum contracts to
>   securely verify Bitcoin transactions without any intermediaries: in
>   short users can pay with Bitcoin to use Ethereum DAPPs.

Comment: From Gitter [ethereum/btcrelay](https://gitter.im/ethereum/btcrelay)  
> Unfortunately not. BTCRelays makes it possible to, on the ethereum side, verify that a given transaction has been executed on the bitcoin blockchain.